Flutter Barcode Scanner Problem When Navigating to Main Screen
I'm using the 'mobile_scanner' package for flutter to scan barcodes in one screen and return to the main screen with a result. Here is my code for the scanner screen:
  Barcode? _barcode;

  void _handleBarcode(BarcodeCapture barcodes) {
    if (mounted) {
      final barcode = barcodes.barcodes.firstOrNull;
      setState(() {
        _barcode = barcode;
      });

      Navigator.pop(context, _barcode!.rawValue);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Scan Barcode'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: MobileScanner(
          controller: MobileScannerController(
              detectionSpeed: DetectionSpeed.noDuplicates),
          onDetect: _handleBarcode,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

And here is the code I use to call the scanner screen:
MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    var result = await Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const ScannerScreen(),
                        ));
                    if (result != null) {
                      setState(() {
                        scannedBarcode = result.toString();
                      });
                    }
                  },  
                  child: const Icon(Icons.barcode_reader),
                ),

For a split of a second I see the result from the 'scanner_screen' and the barcode value is correct, the problem is that a black screen suddenly appears and overtakes the whole application.


I figured it out, based on the official documentation of the 'mobile_scanner' package it seems that it is mandatory to dispose the 'MobileScannerController' in order to get the refreshed results with no bugs. Here is my new code:
Barcode? _barcode;
  MobileScannerController? controller =
      MobileScannerController();
  void _handleBarcode(BarcodeCapture barcodes) async {
    if (mounted) {
      final barcode = barcodes.barcodes.firstOrNull;
      setState(() {
        _barcode = barcode;
      });
      await controller!.dispose();
      Navigator.pop(context, _barcode!.rawValue);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Scan Barcode'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: MobileScanner(
          controller: controller,
          onDetect: _handleBarcode,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

